# Creating a simple TensorFlow Keras.sequential model and receiving all results that are the are same class

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, sequential, softmax

I am trying to create a sequential model witch would classify random groups of vectors to a class. The model consistently classifies  all groups to the same class.

**creating data:**
Each news has 200 random vectors with a dimension of 300.
I want the model to be able to classify each news group to a class

```
 allnews=[]
for j in range(50):
        news=[]
        for i in range(200):
         news.append(np.random.random(300))
        allnews.append(np.array(news))   



#allnews= tf.convert_to_tensor(allnews)
allnews= np.array(allnews)

print(np.shape(allnews))
allnews = allnews.reshape((allnews.shape[0], allnews.shape[1], 300))
print(np.shape(allnews))

lables=[]
for j in range(20):
        lables.append(0)
for j in range(20):
        lables.append(1)
for d in range(10):
        lables.append(2)

lables= tf.convert_to_tensor(lables)
print(lables)
```

**creating the model:**
the model  i am trying to create:

```
YourSequenceLenght=200

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(YourSequenceLenght,300)))
model.add(Dense(300,use_bias=False,kernel_initializer='random_normal',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),activation="linear"))
model.add(SimpleRNN(1, return_sequences=False,kernel_initializer='random_normal',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),use_bias=False,recurrent_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(3,use_bias=False,kernel_initializer='random_normal',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),activation="softmax"))

model.summary() 


METRICS = [
      keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
      keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
      keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
      keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
      keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
      keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
      keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
      keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
]


model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=METRICS)
```

**training and predicting:**

```
print(lables)
lables = keras.utils.to_categorical(y=lables,num_classes= 3)
   # y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y=y_train, num_classes=10)

print(lables)


history = model.fit(allnews,lables,epochs=10)
res= model.predict(allnews)

print(np.shape(res))
import operator
for r in res:
  index, value = max(enumerate(r), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
  print(index)
  print(value)

for r in res:
  print(r)
```

**the outputs from the for prints:**

```
2
0.34069243
2
0.34070647
2
0.33907583
2
0.34005642
2
0.34013948
2
0.34007362
2
0.34028214
2
0.33997294
2
0.34018084
2
0.33995336
2
0.33998552
2
0.33882195
2
0.3401062
2
0.3418465
2
0.33978543
2
0.3396516
2
0.34062216
2
0.3419327
2
0.34114555
2
0.34119973
2
0.3404259
2
0.33981207
2
0.34035686
2
0.34139898
2
0.3398025
2
0.3391234
2
0.34051093
2
0.34120804
2
0.34140897
2
0.34064025
2
0.34133258
2
0.34019342
2
0.3404882
2
0.33930022
2
0.3416659
2
0.3406455
2
0.34054703
2
0.34057957
2
0.3391579
2
0.3395657
2
0.34069654
2
0.3400011
2
0.338789
2
0.34008256
2
0.34080264
2
0.34000066
2
0.340322
2
0.341806
2
0.34178147
2
0.34078327
```

EDIT:

clarification

I am trying to use a model  witch works as follows :
[sigmoid hidden layer(with resurrection ) and softmax projection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znmqJ.png)

Comment: Please take care of language mistakes. The way you present a question is very important to get answers; Also it costs nothing to run a language correction using available online tools

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to learn something from random data. Your model is (randomly) initilialized in such a way that it always predict class 2, and the gradient updates don't steer the weights into any particular direction, because the input is random, so they stay there. Try having your input data be structured instead of random (e.g. `random.random()*tf.one_hot(1,depth=200)` for class 1, `random.random()*tf.one_hot(2, depth=200)` for class 2 and `random.random()*tf.one_hot(3, depth=200)`. Now your values will still be random, but will adhere to a structure.

EDIT:

I took a look at your colab:

1) you can speed up the dataset construction by adding `.numpy()` after the `tf.one_hot`: `tf.one_hot(1).numpy()`.

2) When I changed the model to:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(YourSequenceLenght,300)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(Dense(300,use_bias=False,kernel_initializer='random_normal',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),activation="linear"))
# model.add(SimpleRNN(1, return_sequences=False,kernel_initializer='random_normal',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),use_bias=False,recurrent_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(3,use_bias=False,kernel_initializer='random_normal',kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l1(0.01),activation="softmax"))

model.summary()
```

the accuracy quickly became 100 % after 4 epochs. I think because you only have only 1 output neuron in the `SimpleRNN`, you can't encode enough information to what class it should be, at least not with just 1 `Dense` layer afterwards.

3) You are using `BinaryAccuracy` in your metrics, that doesn't make a lot of sense here. You can just use the normal `accuracy` (as a string) for the accuracy metric (`metrics = ["accuracy", tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(...), ...]`)

Comment: switched the creation for to create the randoms as seggested but the output remains the same

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NG7tFR07t8veYfu3jdVhUEMQsyW-Olry?usp=sharing     `